# Yap Prolog - List

Tags: list, prolog

I have this example of List in Prolog:

```
list_where([Tequila,Whisky,Vodka],bathroom).
list_where([Martini,Musat],kitchen).
list_where([Malibu,Soho],under_the_bed).
list_where([Epita],everywhere).
```

Now, I consult the file in yap (I'm using YAP on Ubuntu 15.10), and I launch this query:

```
list_where(X,bathroom).
```

I have this result:

```
X = [_A,_B,_C] instead of X=[Tequila,Whisky,Vodka]
```

How can i resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An identifier beginning with a capital letter in Prolog is a variable, not an atom. So

```
[Tequila, Whisky, Vodka]
```

is a list of variables. Therefore, when you query `list_where(X, bathroom)` you are getting back a list of uninstantiated variables, which YAP Prolog displays as `[_A,_B,_C]`.

If you want capitalized atoms, use single quotes:

```
['Tequila', 'Whisky', 'Vodka']
```

Or, use lower case:

```
[tequila, whisky, vodka]
```